# Reaper + Guitar Rig + headphones sound issue

Tags: electric-guitar, guitar-effects

I am looking to try and record some music using Guitar rig + reaper. However I am having an issue with sound only playing through the right on my headphones. When I record a piece, and play it back, same problem, only comes through the one headphone

When I use guitar Rig on its own, I have no problem, it sounds great, however when I integrate guitar rig into reaper, and turn on record monitoring, I only hear the sound through the right headphone. Has anyone else had this issue?

This only happens with the guitar rig integration. I have tried the other built in reaper sound effects and they all work fine.

I have tried looking through the audio options but nothing I have tried so far has fixed this. Any help would be much appreciated.

Edit:

Also while I am at it, does anyone know how to solve the latency issue? Is it possible to reduce the latency so that it is barely noticeable? I have a fairly powerful machine, 8 Gig ram, I7 processor, but I am getting an annoying delay when I turn on monitoring mode?

Any suggestions on good methods to fix latency issues?

Edit 2: My temporary fix to the latency issue, is to load up guitar rig outside of reaper, and turn off recording mode in reaper..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

about your first problem :::
I think it should be an output sound setting problem in guitar rig  , if you are creating an stereo track in Reaper try to create a mono audio track there and your problem should be fixed...

about second problem :::
your CPU and RAM power is a part of your work , another part is ::: which sound card or interface you are using?
professional sound cards have a latency or buffer size settings for their inputs... and some sound cards have direct inputs (ignore latency feature)...
but for now if you are using a typical sound hardware and don't have buffer size option in audio interface settings in Reaper , you should download ASIO4ALL and change your audio device in Reaper to ASIO4ALL and control your buffer size from there (lower size = lower latency = higher CPU and memory usage)... for recording it's good to have a buffer size about 256 or 512 but for editing , mixing , mastering probably you need more buffer sizes...
you can download ASIO4ALL from here : http://www.asio4all.com/

Comment: I managed to fix the problem, it was a mistake in my audio settings, I had not set the output properly, I have asio4all. I have lowered my buffer size as you suggested, and the latency problem seems to have gone away now. Cheers

Comment: good for you ;)