# Some questions about prospects of using MIDI a keyboard with MilkyTracker

Tags: software, keyboard, midi, electronic-music, synthesizer

I have an electronic keyboard (Casio CTK-4000). I want to use it with MilkyTracker on Ubuntu. After connecting it to my laptop with a USB A/B printer cable and doing some aconnect routing, I was able to make it work, that is I'm now able to control a single channel, but only play a single note at a time. I am wondering if it is possible to get more out of this, specifically:

- From what I've gathered so far, it's not possible to play chords on a single channel, it's a limitation (feature?) of MilkyTracker. But is it possible to make it recognize multiple pressed notes and play the chip-tune arpeggio instead? Or does the arpeggio have to be done on the keyboard's side?
- Is it possible to make the keyboard control multiple channels instead?
- Is it possible to tweak the keyboard latency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- I don't have any idea about your first question but its a bad limition.
- but about your second question answer is yes. you should just enable monitor/record on Tracks (or channels) you want to play on them but keep that in mind every channel is assigning to an instrument... so if you want chords of one instrument you need to move all of notes played to one channel , or if its not possible in MilkyTracker you should copy your instrument on all channels (this may need a huge RAM take care for crashes).
- and about your last question you can find your answer [here](https://music.stackexchange.com/a/15726/9674)